# How can I get controller scope reliably in directive?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Let's say I have a directive that simply print out its scope id

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'directive scope {{$id}}',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      //console.log('controller scope', 'HOW?');
    }
  };
});
```

**Case 1:**
It is used in controller like the following as usual.
It prints out 003 for both controller and directive.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  controller scope : {{$id}}
  <div my-customer></div>
</div>
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3UyDwk?p=preview

**Case 2:**
Next, I used the same directive in controller like the following within ng-include and ng-repeat.
The following prints out scope ids, 003, 004, 005… and so on.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  controller scope : {{$id}}
  <div ng-include="'ng-repeat.html'"></div>
</div>
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6vMpCt?p=preview

I understand ng-include and ng-repeat create its own scope.

**Question :**
My question is "how can I get controller scope reliably in directive?"

From the above case 1 and case 2, I want to get scope "003" in directive with the same code.

I can use `scope` for case 1,
but for case 2, I need to use `scope.$parent.$parent`
and if I use ng-repeat only, I need to use `scope.$parent`
What if I use it inside ng-include and ng-include? `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent…`?

I was searching for code like `scope.controllerScope()`, which does not exist.

My use case is to call a function in controller from directive without using isolated scope.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Since the controller scope is a parent to your directive's, any function set on your controller is available (via inheritance) to your directive if it hasn't been superseded.  So if all you need is to call a function on the controller scope then you can do that without directly accessing it's scope: [updated fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/nuBGNZbKhfDkcZeVXZXN?p=preview).

Comment: @KayakDave, thanks. it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

#### I've tried some techniques but this is the best solution I found:

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bA6jww?p=preview

**We can mutate all controllers by decorating the $controllerProvider:**

```
app.config(function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    return function (expression, locals) {
      if (expression != angular.noop) {
        locals.$scope.$controllerId = locals.$scope.$id;
      }
      return $delegate(expression,locals)
    }
  }]); 
})
```

**Now we can data-bind it through the prototype chain:**

```
{{$controllerId}}
```

One caveat is that **isolated scopes cannot inherit this value** but I guess it's a wanted behavior since these scopes do not inherit from outer controllers anyway.

Comment: Thank you. This will be useful when I build directive for my own usage. Another caveat is that this behaviour is not controllerable if I build a public module, i.e. [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)

Comment: Please describe your use case. I have more ways but it depends on what you need exacly